# How to set the radio button value checked by default in struts2?

Tags: struts2

The code I am using is:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <s:radio name="dlrMaintenanceVO.dbsVO.substitutionMethod" id="substitution" label="" list="#{'M':'Moves History'}" /> 

      <br/>
      <s:radio name="dlrMaintenanceVO.dbsVO.substitutionMethod" id="substitution" label="" list="#{'R':'Reports History'}" value="R"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This should make radio button with R value as checked by default. But this thing is not happening. Any suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Please change value to  `value="'R'"`

Answer (score 1):

I'm okay with following code to set default value in radio button in struts 2.Type **checked="true"** you want to default in radio tag.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <s:radio name="dlrMaintenanceVO.dbsVO.substitutionMethod" id="substitution" label="" list="#{'M':'Moves History'}" checked="true"/> 

      <br/>
      <s:radio name="dlrMaintenanceVO.dbsVO.substitutionMethod" id="substitution" label="" list="#{'R':'Reports History'}" value="R"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `R` should have correct value set in your action class.All you need to set the required value in your action class for `R` and based on the value it will select the appropriate radio button

Comment: could you specify how to do that i am not getting it properly.

Comment: create a property in your action class and set its value, in your case it should be "R" this is all you need to do

Comment: I have set the properties already. I got the problem it was in "value" attribute. It should be written as: value="%{'R'}"